# How to replace every occurrence of a string in dataSetRow?

Tags: birt

I have some very large rptdesign report definition files.

I would like to do something like in the example below:

```
<expression name="expression">dataSetRow["WORK_DESCRIPTION"].replace(new RegExp('&amp;lt;', 'g'), '&lt;');</expression>
```

But for any occurrence of string in any dataset in any cell in any row.

Is this possible to do in rptdesign?

Or is there other way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to create a style (use predefined data style) and add a map to it.  Put a script in first expression like:

```
    importPackage(Packages.java.lang);
    if( _jsContext.getContent().getValue() instanceof String ){
      if( _jsContext.getContent().getValue() == "S18_1749" ){
       _jsContext.getContent().setValue(_jsContext.getContent().getValue()+"--");
      }
    }
    true;
```

This will always return true.  Set the second expression to false, so the map never occurs.  It is a bit ugl